# Переход с ajax-табов jQuery.

Tags: ajax, html5-history-api

В торопях не подумав начал использовать табы jquery (http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax). Вот даже код Вам на обозрение:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <p><?= $company->title ?></p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/ajax/navigator/about/<?= $company->alias ?>">О компании</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ajax/navigator/goods/<?= $company->alias ?>">Товары</a></li>
<!-- Тут ещё дофига <li>-шек -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Всё работает на ура, но в чем собственно проблема. Вся эта красота выдаётся на запрос /compmany/companyName. И изначально показывается только текст о компании. Во вкладках - дофига всего. Боюсь яндекс не сможет пройтись по табам jquery, и сомневаюсь что Гугл всё прочтёт. Скажите, если мои сомнения напрасны. Иначе вот вопрос: где взять библиотеку и какую библиотеку (наслышен о html5-history-api, но брать первую, что под руки попадётся боюсь - хочу проверенное решение использовать) чтоб реализовать всю эту замуту тоже аяксом и со сменой урлов, да так, чтоб роботам понравилось? Заранее всех отзывчивых благодарю.

Comment: роботы пойдут по ссылкам, прописанным в href. тут проблем нету.

/ajax/ из ссылок только уберите. т.е., нужно чтоб на один урл два разных ответа было: для ajax'а и для обычного запроса. на сервере проверяйте заголовок X-Requested-With (существует ли и равен ли 'XmlHttpRequest'), в зависимости от него отдавайте разный - частичный или полный контент. history тут ни при чем.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю вам нужно это:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#tabs").bind("tabsshow", function(event, ui) { 
    window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
})
```

После выбора закладки дописывает в хеш адреса `a href`.

**UPDATE.** 
Гугл обрабатывает хештеги так:

1. Сразу после # должен идти !. То есть URL должен выглядеть как-то так: http://example.com/index.html#!ajaxSection.
2. Бот, увидев подобный хештег в ссылке, попробует сходить по адресу http://example.com/index.html?*escaped_fragment*=ajaxSection. Вы, соответственно, должны по этому адресу отдать видимый контент для индексации.

[пруф](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)

Comment: А не проще юзать нормальный давно работающий HTML5 History API? Зачем городить старые костыли, когда есть возможность делать все нормально и с новыми возможностями. А для старых браузеров просто использовать [рассширения][1] и ссылки нормальные будут и роботы по ним ходить будут.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/93523#93918

Comment: @devote , спасибо, слышал про HTML5 History API, но никогда не вчитывался. Очень полезная штука.

Comment: доп. вопрос. чем .live() от .bind() отличается?